# Creating Item category type throw "6000: A business validation error has occurred while processing your request" error

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using v3-php-sdk, creating items non category type works well.

The problem is when the item is use to be category eg.

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Item
    [FullyQualifiedName] => Item
    [Type] => Category
)
```

Then if I call

```
Item::create($arrayItem)
```

It generated object like this.

```
QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPItem Object
        (
            [Name] => Item
            [Sku] => 
            [Description] => 
            [Active] => 
            [SubItem] => 
            [ParentRef] => 
            [Level] => 
            [FullyQualifiedName] => Item
            [Taxable] => 
            [SalesTaxIncluded] => 
            [PercentBased] => 
            [UnitPrice] => 
            [RatePercent] => 
            [Type] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPCustomFieldTypeEnum Object
                (
                    [value] => Category
                )

            [PaymentMethodRef] => 
            [UOMSetRef] => 
            [IncomeAccountRef] => 
            [PurchaseDesc] => 
            [PurchaseTaxIncluded] => 
            [PurchaseCost] => 
            [ExpenseAccountRef] => 
            [COGSAccountRef] => 
            [AssetAccountRef] => 
            [PrefVendorRef] => 
            [AvgCost] => 
            [TrackQtyOnHand] => 
            [QtyOnHand] => 
            [QtyOnPurchaseOrder] => 
            [QtyOnSalesOrder] => 
            [ReorderPoint] => 
            [ManPartNum] => 
            [DepositToAccountRef] => 
            [SalesTaxCodeRef] => 
            [PurchaseTaxCodeRef] => 
            [InvStartDate] => 
            [BuildPoint] => 
            [PrintGroupedItems] => 
            [SpecialItem] => 
            [SpecialItemType] => 
            [ItemGroupDetail] => 
            [ItemAssemblyDetail] => 
            [AbatementRate] => 
            [ReverseChargeRate] => 
            [ServiceType] => 
            [ItemCategoryType] => 
            [ItemEx] => 
            [Id] => 
            [SyncToken] => 
            [MetaData] => 
            [CustomField] => 
            [AttachableRef] => 
            [domain] => 
            [status] => 
            [sparse] => 
        )
```

However, it always throw error for this object, on my research they are saying that we should not pass 0 or negative number for eg. unitprice or other fields but if that's the case the sdk is the one generated this object and I just provide the data I have.

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For Sandbox, category is not enabled by default. You will need to go to this link to enable it on Sandbox: https://sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/app/categorymigration

Try create a free-trial production company, everything should be working correctly"

As per Hao_Lu (Intuit Developer Group)

Click this [link](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00005LYeYA/quickbooks-create-item-via-api-throw-error-code-6000-quickbooksonlineapiexceptionvalidationexception-6000-a-business-validation-error-has-occurred-while-processing-your-request?s1oid=00DG0000000COk8&OpenCommentForEdit=1&s1nid=0DBG0000000blK7&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0050f000009WSt5&emtm=1522947945351&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `[UnitPrice] =>` is empty. You will need to pass in some positive value if that's the error message you are getting

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Item
    [FullyQualifiedName] => Item
    [Type] => Category
    [UnitPrice] => 1
)
```

Comment: Yeh but for creating category it doesn't need to have any UnitPrice.
Refer here https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/item;
CATEGORY REQUEST BODY
SAMPLE REQUEST
{
  "Name": "Trees",
  "Type":"Category"
}